# $.mobile.changePage(); don't trigger in my next page?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

im using `$.mobile.changePage();` to go to a page. What's odd is in my index page it works but if i click on my next page and trigger the swipedown the`mobile.change` it doesn't work now.. I know that my swipedown event is not the issue here cause tried to comment the`mobile.changepage`and insert an alert function and it fired.

Process:
In my Index page. `$.mobile.changePage` event work

```
$(document).delegate('.front-page-down','swipedown', function (event) {
    $.mobile.changePage('#notification', { transition: "slidedown"});
});
```

Go to a next page e.g page2 and tried to trigger my swipe event, mobile.changePage doesn't work.

```
$(document).delegate('.sns-down','swipedown', function (event) {
    //$.mobile.changePage('#featured', { transition: "slidedown"}); // this don't work in my next page
    alert("BOOM SNS");
});
```

Anyone know why this happens? The function changePage is enclose to an delegate function. I'm not using any document.ready() function.

FYI. For the mobile.changePage to work in my page2 I would have to refresh the page manually. hmmm

Help anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do that with jQuery Mobile

```
$('.sns-down').each( function(){
    $(this).live('swipedown', function (event) {
        //$.mobile.changePage('#featured', { transition: "slidedown"}); // this don't work in my next page
        alert("BOOM SNS");
    });
});
```

if that doesn't work.. you can try to reload jquery mobile for that page with:

```
$.mobile.activePage.page("destroy").page();
```

before you bind the swipedown event.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this link](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/page-scripting.html)
at the "Scripts & styles in the head" section you could find the solution.
put your script into the body tag and then you don't need to refresh your page! 
I hope that is useful for you problem